# Nodemailer email posting but says pending

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm trying to use Nodemailer in a React/Express app I'm working on and on the server it says it's posting but in the network tab its showing pending and then it never goes through? Here's my code:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
require("dotenv").config();
// router.get('/', () => {
// resizeBy.send('Welcome to my email form')
// });
module.exports = () => {
  router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log("inside event handler")
    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      service: 'Gmail',
      port: 465,
      auth: {
        user: process.env.EMAIL,
        pass: process.env.PASSWORD
      }
    });
    let mailOptions = {
      from: process.env.EMAIL,
      to: `${req.body.values.email}`,
      subject: `Message from: ${process.env.EMAIL}`,
      html: `
    <h3>Information</h3>
    <ul>
    <li>Name: ${req.body.values.name}</li>
    <li>Email: ${req.body.values.email}</li>
    </ul>
  
    <h3>Message</h3>
    <p>${req.body.values.message}</p>
    `
    }
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, response) => {
      if (err) {
        res.send(err)
        console.log("Error happened in send email", err)
      } else {
        res.send('Success! Message sent!')
        console.log("Message sent")
      }
    })
    transporter.close();


  })

  return router;
}
```

Comment: do you see any of your `console.log` messages in the server output?

Comment: I do, from my client side. Here's the request from there, I am seeing "handling submit event" in my console:
```
const submitEmail = (e) => {
   console.log("handling submit event")
   e.preventDefault();
   axios
   .post('/api/email', values)
   .then((res) => {
     console.log("Server responded")
     setValues({
       name: "",
       email: "",
       message: "",
       status: true
     })
     .catch(err => {
       console.log(err);
       window.alert("Email not sent")
     });
  
    });

 };
```

Comment: if you don't see any logs from the node.js server then your request is mapped incorrectly probably. Double check `/api/email` actually maps to the express route you showed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't need to use [transporter.close()](https://nodemailer.com/smtp/pooled/#transporterclose) since you aren't pooling connections. Using it in this context is probably your problem.

`transporter.sendMail()` is async so you are sending mail and then immediately closing it with `transporter.close()`. This means the `sendMail` callback isn't fired, which in turn means `res.send()` is never sent, which results in your never ending and pending http request to your client.

I suggest removing the `transporter.close()` line and retrying.

Comment: Tried commenting it out and unfortunately it's still not working